# Flutter shared_preferences not working in production (Google Play Store) on Android

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) 2.0.15 Flutter package to create an autologin feature in my app.
In Android, when the app is running in debug mode everything is working fine but as soon as the app is released to Google Play Store the autologin feature doesn't work anymore.
I haven't tested it on iOS just yet..

I've tried building the release using `flutter build appbundle --release --no-shrink` as suggested on other older threads found on Google. But this doesn't fix the issue when uploaded to Google Play Store.

I am loading the shared preferences instance through a singleton class instantiated in my main function:

Main function:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await PrefsSingleton().init();
...
```

Singleton:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class PrefsSingleton {
  static final PrefsSingleton _instance = PrefsSingleton._internal();

  late final SharedPreferences _prefs;

  factory PrefsSingleton() {
    return _instance;
  }

  PrefsSingleton._internal();

  Future<SharedPreferences> init() async => _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  Future<bool> setBool(String key, bool value) => _prefs.setBool(key, value);

  bool? getBool(String key) => _prefs.getBool(key);

  Future<bool> setString(String key, String value) => _prefs.setString(key, value);

  String? getString(String key) => _prefs.getString(key);

  Future<bool> setJsonEncodedString(String key, dynamic value) => _prefs.setString(key, json.encode(value));

  dynamic getJsonDecodedString(String key) {
    var jsonString = _prefs.getString(key);

    if (jsonString != null) {
      return jsonDecode(jsonString);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Where I am doing the autologin:

```
class AutoLogin implements StartupTask {
  @override
  Future<dynamic> runTask() async {
    var alreadyLoggedIn = PrefsSingleton().getBool("user.isLoggedIn") ?? false;

    if (alreadyLoggedIn) {
      var domain = PrefsSingleton().getString("user.domain");
      var pincode = PrefsSingleton().getString("user.pincode");

      await PrefsSingleton().setBool("user.isLoggedIn", false);

      if (domain != null && pincode != null) {
        var loggedIn = await ApiUserRepo().loginUser(domain, pincode);
        if (loggedIn) {
          await PluginSyncRepo().getSyncData();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues and found a solution?
Could this maybe have something to do with the fact that I am using a prerelease of [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod/versions/2.0.0-dev.9) 2.0.0-dev.9?

------- Info -------

- Flutter version: 3.0.5
- Dart version: 2.17.6
- Build gradle version: 7.0.0

------- Installed packages -------

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.9
device_info_plus: ^4.0.0
percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
url_launcher: ^6.1.0
rest_client: ^2.1.4
crypto: ^3.0.2
catcher: ^0.7.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
uuid: ^3.0.6
flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.3.4
intl: ^0.17.0
image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
connectivity_plus: ^2.3.2
json_annotation: ^4.5.0
reorderables: ^0.5.0
cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
string_validator: ^0.3.0
image: ^3.2.0
heic_to_jpg: ^0.2.0
path_provider: ^2.0.11
package_info_plus: ^1.4.2
camera: ^0.10.0+1
dropdown_button2: ^1.7.2

Comment: How do you know it is `shared_preferences` that is the issue?

Comment: Well I cant be sure. But since everything else is working in production my guess is that the issue is caused by the shared_preferences package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497041/which-permission-to-use-for-shared-preferences-androidflutter might be usefull

Comment: Or the code where you use shared_preferences...

Comment: @Jan-Stepien My code is also using a null check statement similar to the one in the other post. I will give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: @RobertSandberg in my code the shared preferences instance is wrapped in a singleton class and only "initialized" once in main. Could this be the troublemaker?
I will update my question so you can see the singleton class.

Comment: A thing to consider...It is not guaranteed that the cache held by SharedPreferences that you create when getting that instance is in sync with the values on the device. So if you only get the instance once, that could result in unwanted behavior.

Comment: @RobertSandberg Thanks. I guess you are right. It could also explain the problem right? Without having very deep insight into how the shared_preferences package work, I would assume that more aggressive caching is enabled in release mode. I will refactor my code to not use the singleton and retrieve the shared preferences instance every time I want to use it. I will let you know if it works